# Dusk не может распознать json

Tags: laravel, phpunit, testng

Пробую запустить пробный тест на dusk. Локально проект находит, только не может распознать json респонс. Лара 5.5.39, даск 2.0.14, пхпюнит 5.7.27

```
    chernya@chernya:~/projects/project/app$ php artisan dusk
    PHPUnit 5.7.27 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

    E                                                                   1 / 1 (100%)

    Time: 3.92 seconds, Memory: 18.00MB

    There was 1 error:

    1) Tests\Browser\ExampleTest::testBasicExample
    Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\WebDriverException: JSON decoding of remote response failed.
    Error code: 4
    The response: '<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="ru"><head>

ERRORS!
Tests: 1, Assertions: 0, Errors: 1.
```

Comment: Ну так в ответе ни разу не json.

Comment: Серьёзно?). Возможно я неправильно сформулировал вопрос. Почему в ответе приходит HTML,а  не json?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В файле DuskTestCase.php `RemoteWebDriver::create` у меня был указан URL http://lcalhost.loc, нужно указывать URL Selenium сервера http://localhost:4444/wd/hub